# Parse transcript allele to protein

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have somthing like `NM_000023.2:c.488dupG` and I would like to parse it to protein, for example for `NM_000016.5:c.127G>A` the result would be `p.Glu43Lys`

Would you know if there is any way to do it? I have 2000 to be done, so I should automate it.

Answer (score -1):

I know how to do it, whit this library: https://hgvs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Please expand your answer - see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)